# Exchange 2010, 2013 and 2016 maximum mailbox size

Tags: exchange, mailbox, limits

Which is the maximum size limit for a single mailbox in exchange 2010, 2013 and 2016?

Answer (score 2):

The default limit is 2gb.
However the only limit will be the physical limit of the database, which is 2TB.

However a mailbox of that size will be almost impossible to view. The practical limit would be somewhere between 30 and 60gb, depending on the Outlook version being used.

Simon.

Answer (score 1):

To know about the memory consumption in Exchange, Please visit this informative [Blog](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/32093/How-to-Reduce-Mailbox-Database-Size-of-Exchange-2010-2013-2016-Server.html) regarding Mailbox Database Size of Exchange 2010, 2013, 2016 Server. As Size for mailboxes Different version in Exchange for Example:

- For 2007: Maximum storage allows 250 GB and 50 storage groups
- For 2010: Maximum total drive storage capacity 2TB and 100 Storage groups.
- For 2013: Maximum storage allows 2TB, and storage groups reduced from 100 to 50.

Answer (score 0):

The default limit for a mailbox is 2GB which can be extended to unlimited. But 
unlimited again will be restricted by the max database size which is in Exchange 2010 16TB (default is 1TB).

I recommend to not look at the maximum mailbox size but look after the **recommended** max mailbox size.

The Exchange Team wrote a blog article about this: [Recommended Mailbox Size Limits](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2005/03/14/recommended-mailbox-size-limits/).

Currently Microsoft [offers max 100GB per mailbox via Office 365](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx#StorageLimits), and I would strongly recommend to not extend this limit. They have a highly skilled tech team; they should know why they set this limit.

I see an Exchange mailbox always as a type of work space. Therefore I recommend always to have some archiving rules in place. People shouldn't hoard mails over 2 years which don't have any relevance anymore.

See also MSDN TechNet Magazine 2012 article [Microsoft Exchange Server 2010: Exchange Archiving and Compliance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875169.aspx).

Answer (score -3):

The maximum size limit for a single mailbox in exchange is 2GB.

Comment: Where did you get this number from? It's completely wrong. You might be thinking of the maximum file size for an ANSI format PST file.